# Changing github user to organization

Tags: github, github-organizations

So, this might be a stupid question but, our clients depend on some of our **public repos**, by ours I mean the **github user** of the company. It was made a long time ago, and now we are considering converting to organization (for machine users and whatnot) but we are not sure about the consequences of doing this.

Can anyone tell me if the repos suffer any kind of change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main consequence is the remote repository URL <del>will change, which means the clients will need to update their 'origin' of the local copy they have.</del>

Since the history will *not* have changed when the repository moves from personal to organization, they won't have anything else to do.

```
cd /path/to/local/clone/of/repo
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<newOrg>/<aRepo.git>
```

2022: it does not change, see the last section.

As [rob006](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5812455/rob006) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010075/changing-github-user-to-organization/50014054#comment87055159_50014054), it is not needed at first, Since GitHub will redirect the URL of the old repo to the new one, since [May 2013](https://blog.github.com/2013-05-16-repository-redirects-are-here/).
But if the same user repo is recreated, then the clients will have an issue.

---

Warning (2022): [jmon12](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11222693/jmon12) notes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010075/changing-github-user-to-organization/50014054?noredirect=1#comment128034922_50014054) that the URL does *not* change. From [this thread](https://github.community/t/transforming-to-an-organization/18564)

> When [converting](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-personal-account-settings/converting-a-user-into-an-organization) an individual account into an organization, the repositories do not move.
> Do keep in mind, while transforming the account to an organization, you will be required to designate a another user account as an organizational owner.

Comment: GitHub redirects to new URL, so this should be no problem as long you don't create new repo with old URL.

Comment: @rob006 Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, with a link to the official GitHub page.

Comment: Awesome! Now if the organization has the same name as the user, wouldn't they have the same url?

Comment: @FranciscoRangel Yes, but can you define an organisation when its name is *already* taken by a user? I don't think so (to be tested though)

Comment: It turns out it just makes the user the org, no urls changed

Comment: From this [answer](https://github.community/t/transforming-to-an-organization/18564) on the github community, this answer seems partially wrong. If you turn the personal account into an organization account **without changing its name**, I don't see any reason for the URL to change.

Comment: @jmon12 Good point, thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I'd just like to confirm that indeed, if the organization name is the same as the ex-user account, the URL doesn't change. I just tested it.

Comment: @jmon12 Perfect, thank you for the follow-up. I have edited the answer to make that clearer.